# Kohana 3.x - Return from action ASAP if error encountered

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-3

Is there a kohana equivalent to the following (derived from Symfony 1.4):

```
public function ajax_win() {

    try {
        ...
    } catch Exception($e) {

        $response['errors'] = array($e->getMessage());

        $this->template->content = json_encode($response);

        // Id like to return here, early return if error encountered
        // Symfony example
        // Is there a Kohana counterpart, or just do empty return?
        return sfView::NONE;
    }

    // More code here, which is why I want early return, so I don't have to nest conditionals
    ....
}
```

Comment: What is keeping you back? There is no expected result for actions and for all system/module methods you [can check the API](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/). Or am I missing something (no knowledge of Symfony here)?

Comment: Just curious what the correct "kohana" procedure is here, just a blank return?

Comment: Well that depends on where you're at in the code. Do you just want to end the current scope/method or the whole procedure?

Comment: I just want to early return from the action.

Comment: @MikePurcell I think I might understand it now. You are in a controller(_template) executing an action and want to return early while displaying only the JSON encoded `$response`?

Comment: Correct. Obviously I could just do a return, but with Symfony you need to indicate what you are returning, otherwise it will try to load a template, or you may get the dreaded sfView stop exception error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you are in a situation inside a Controller's action and don't want any of the other content to be shown but your JSON encoded variable.

You don't need to `return` anything, as this is not how Controllers work. However, you need to modify [`$this->response`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Controller#property:response).

If you are in the environment of [`Controller_Template`](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide-api/Controller_Template), it is also important to set `$this->auto_render` to `FALSE` (or something that is not `TRUE`), so the `after()` method does not override everything you tried.

This code is untested but should do the trick.

```
public function ajax_win() {

    try {
        ...
    } catch Exception($e) {
        $data['errors'] = array($e->getMessage());
        $response = new Response();
        $response->body(json_encode($data));
        $this->response = $response;
        return;
    }

    // More code here, which is why I want early return, so I don't have to nest conditionals
    ....
}
```

For more information, you can check the guide, where the [Request Flow](http://kohanaframework.org/3.3/guide/kohana/flow) of an application is described in detail.

Comment: Thanks, just wanted to check if there was Kohana specific return which was needed. For the record, some frameworks, Symfony for example, require that a non-empty value be returned, otherwise it assumes success and will attempt to load the template.